# Communicate independent C modules

Tags: c, callback, architecture, spi, can-bus

I implemented a library for an external CAN driver IC connected to an Arduino board through SPI in a hobby can project. As I started to work in other ECUs connected to the CAN network, I realised that my approach was not flexible enough and requires a refactoring in order to provide a more generic solution so that I can reuse the same architecture in other ECUs with and different CAN drivers.

At this moment, my CAN driver library implementation manage directly the SPI communication with the IC in order to configure the filters and read/write the CAN frames. The sequence to communicate with the IC looks like this:

```
[Cyclical tasks] -> [CanDrv.h] -> [SPI.h] -> [CAN driver IC]
```

There are two problems with this approach:

1. The implementation of the CanDrv.h requires the SPI, so in a different board it shall be adapted to a different SPI interface.
2. The interface with the rest of the system is IC dependent, so if I change the CAN driver IC (and therefore the CanDrv module), I should re-write all the modules that call it.

My idea is to define a generic CAN interface module that uses services from the Candrv.h and handle the SPI communication, so the system upstream will be independent from the IC and the CanDrv.h implementation is not SPI interface dependent:

```
[Cyclical tasks] -> [CanIf.h] -> [SPI.h] -> [CAN driver IC]

                       ^

                   [CanDrv.h]
```

The problem now is how I implement CanIf so that it can act as "bridge" between the CanDrv and the SPI modules. I read something about callbacks functions, but I am not sure if this would be the best approach and in any case  I don't know how to implement it.

Can anyone advice me about this approach? Is there any other method to make my code more flexible?

Thanks

Comment: This is a problem created by Arduino. Modern microcontrollers use on-chip CAN controllers, using external ones is a thing of the 1990s. I'd advise to throw Arduino in the garbage where it belongs and instead pick a professional platform with the CAN controller on-chip, then write a HAL above the CAN driver if needed.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but I don't think this is the correct solution. In my experience in the automotive software industry, I have seen some projects where the selected processor or SoC did not have an on-chip CAN controller and an external one was required. This is due to performance requirements or to constraints in the power consumption in sleep mode that limits IC selection.

Comment: No, that's wrong. An external controller means more current and much more latency. And most importantly in an automotive context: much more expensive BOM. The only reason you pick an external one is because you pre-maturely got married to one paricular MCU and then later realized you need CAN.